# EditText focus method not working as expected in android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, focusable

I have a button "show" and when the button is clicked , the edit text box must not be editable and when I click next, I must give back the focus to edit text box. I tried the below code

```
  showans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               editText.setFocusable(false);
     }
  next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setFocusable(true);
            editText.setClickable(true);
      }
 }
```

I tried changing values between setFocusable and setClickable but nothing helped. When I click the showans button for the first time, the edit box loses focus and its not clickable though I set the value to true when I click the "next" button and all these buttons .All these text boxes and buttons are dynamically generated.Any help would be great !! Thanks

Comment: What was the actual problem while creating dynamic Buttons?

Comment: No I just want to mention this. I don't have any problems because of that @AbhishekPatel

Comment: You can use setEnabled() method to completely disable or enable the edittext view.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works @MalithLakshan

Comment: Use _setEnabled()_

Comment: @Anusha Don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); for uneditable EditText
```

and

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) 

to make it editable
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change to  `editText.requestFocus();`

You can use `editText.clearFocus();`

Comment: Where am I suppose to add this ? when the next button is clicked ?@Arshid KV

Comment: No its not working

Comment: You can use `editText.clearFocus()`

Comment: Where Am i supposed to add this

Answer (score 0):

You can use setEnabled() method to disable or enable the editText

```
//to disable
editText.setEnabled(false);
//to re enable
editText.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `setFocusableInTouchMode` - so your code will change to something like this:

```
showans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               editText.setFocusable(false);
               editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
     }
  next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setFocusable(true);
            editText.setClickable(true);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      }
 }
```

Give this a try and let me know if it helps.